# Was the Eatonville of "Their Eyes Were Watching God" modeled exactly on the real town of the same name or simply inspired by it?

Tags: zora-neale-hurston, their-eyes-were-watching-god

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Their_Eyes_Were_Watching_God#Inspirations_and_influences):

> The all-black Eatonville of *Their Eyes Were Watching God* is based on the all-black town of the same name in which Hurston grew up. The town's weekly announced in 1889, "Colored People of the United States: Solve the great race problem by securing a home in Eatonville, Florida, a Negro city governed by negroes."

How similar are the fictional and real towns? Was it directly modeled after the real town, or simply inspired by it?